# Neo4j on aws instance with java Rest Binding

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j, neo4jrestclient

I have created an AWS EC2 instance running Neo4j(Community AMI) and i have connected to the end point successfully through the browser.now i want to access my db from java application through the Restbinding

```
    `RestAPI graphDB = new RestAPIFacade("EC2_ENDPOINT:7474/db/data/");
    QueryEngine engine=new RestCypherQueryEngine(graphDB); 

     QueryResult<Map<String,Object>> result = engine.query("start n=node(*) return count(n) as total", Collections.EMPTY_MAP); 

     Iterator<Map<String, Object>> iterator=result.iterator(); 

     if(iterator.hasNext()) { 

       Map<String,Object> row= iterator.next(); 

       System.out.print("Total nodes: " + row.get("total")); `
```

i have tested this code for localhost and got results but when i try this this Exception occurs!

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading as JSON '<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /db/data/cypher. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>
```

can anyone help me here.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you access your database manually using http://EC2_ENDPOINT:7474/db/data/ ?

Did you open the port in the AWS security config. And did you configure your Neo4j server in `conf/neo4j-server.properties` to listen on the public interface?

Comment: database was accessible manually. and i also opened the port on security config. how do i configure the neo4j server to listen to public interface?